# Most straightforward way of creating a video file from frames of raw bitmap data?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, video-capture, video-encoding

This *has* to be really straightforward. :)

I've got a Forms app I've put together using a motley mixture of managed and non-managed C++.

I'd like to type a filename into a dialog and then click a button to request that an incoming sequence of frames be rolled into an .avi file of that name.

My frame data is currently in raw RGB24 data, on its way into something a little more friendly for display in real time on my form, but getting ahead of myself I'd just like to know what the best way of hooking in the 'Open New Video File' and 'Save Current Frame to Video File' mechanisms would be.

My new frame gets rendered in the Form's Paint method and I'm sure this isn't going to be the best place to just strap in the call to save, but where is?

Any assistance in clarifying the most efficient and sensible way of adding what, in English at least, is a fairly rounded and straightford task, would be most kindly welcomed.

Comment: The easiest solution so far is to link in OpenCV and use the VideoWriter component which does pretty much what I want to do. It would be nice to know if there was a native way of doing this which was as straightforward and which sits nicely in a managed environment.

Answer (score 0):

While I've not tried this, I found a link on MSDN which pointed to codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx

By the looks of it, the codeproject article's source wraps the not-so-straightforward Win32 AVI APIs into a relatively-straightforward .net library.  It is .net 1.1, however, with all the glory and frustrations that one may expect from it.

Here is the MSDN article which lead me to that location on codeproject: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/64d4dc64-8647-433c-add7-5d23daf6b360